# Node: Post to a route, according to dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, post

I have a form.
Inside the form, the user selects an item from a dropdown.
Then clicks submit, and the selected item gets POSTed to a specific route.

This is the code:

```
<form role="form" action="/converter" method="POST" id="sc-form">
    <label for="model">Choose a model:</label>
    <select name="model" id="model">
            <% data.forEach(function(dat) { %>
            <option value="<%= dat %>"> <%= dat %> </option>
            <% }); %>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Convert file" />
</form>
```

Now, what i want to do is add another dropdown menu, inside the same form.

For simplicity, let's say the dropdown will have two options, option A and option B.

What this extra dropdown will do, is select where the item from the first dropdown will get POSTed to. In other words, the POST action will be changed based on the selection from the second dropdown.

If option A is selected, then the item from the first dropdown will be POSTed to route A.
If option B is selected, then the item from the first dropdown will be POSTed to route B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener on the route dropdown:

```html
<select id="route-select">
    <option value="route a">A</option>
    <option value="route b">B</option>
</select>
```

```js
const routeSelect = document.getElementById('route-select');
const form = document.getElementById('sc-form');

routeSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    form.action = e.target.value;
});
```

Comment: Nice idea. The second code snippet goes in a script at the bottom of the page, correct?

Comment: Right, inside a <script> block or external js file